# Is openSSL encryption enough?

Tags: php, openssl, aes, mcrypt

I have sensitive information stored in a database which goes through the following process:

1. user enters information through webform.
2. information entered is encrypted using AES 256-bit and salted using unique id to each user (although this is stored in the *same* database, and sometimes same table).
3. The encrypted pass 1 data is THEN parse through openssl_pub_encrypt function
4. data is stored in mysql database with fieldtype: varbinary

to decrypt the data:

1. the private key is stored OFF the server and must be uploaded in a temporary file EVERY time the data needs to be retrieved
2. the code runs through openssl_private_decrypt
3. the code is run through a decrypt with the same salt and AES-256 script.

What I am wondering is running the information through the AES-256 bit in this instance  even worth it (since key is offline, and the salt is already stored within the table if the data ever became compromised)?

Answer (score 3):

Salting makes no sense on symetrically encrypted data, which is what you've got with AES-256. If anything, it'd just make any potential cracker's job easier by putting some known plaintext within the data. After all, ANY key will "decrypt" the data, but only one key will produce the original data. By putting a chunk of known plaintext in there, you've made it far easier to determine if the key being used is valid or not ("is salt text there, if so key is valid").

If the data's so sensitive that you have to take these precautions, I'd be more worried about the exposure window when the key file is actually stored on the server, as well as the traces it will leave behind in memory and on-disk, even after you've removed the file.

Comment: i apologize, i really am not salting the data, i use the unique ID for each member as the key (so everybody's key is different)

Answer (score 1):

There is no point encrypting the data with a key that is available in the same place as the encrypted data.

However, it would be an advantage if you used a separate public/private key pair for each user - that way, if a private key leaks, you are only exposing one of your records instead of all of them.

By the way, `openssl_public_encrypt()` / `openssl_private_decrypt()` is not really the right function to use - it's a lower-level function intended for encrypting randomly generated keys, not to directly operate on the data.  The right, higher-level functions are [`openssl_seal()`](http://php.net/openssl_seal) / [`openssl_open()`](http://php.net/openssl_open).

Comment: thanks for the latter point. Regarding separate public/private key pairs for each user - this seems unreasonable given we may have 10,000 records. Having to generate pair for each record, then storing them, then having to upload and run through the decryption for each one would be near impossible. I do like your point about 'one instead of all of them' but I'm not sure that route is even feasible in these circumstances.

Comment: @JM4: Ahh, I had assumed from your description that you were selecting individual records to decrypt at decryption-time, rather than all of them.  A single key should be fine.